# JSP pass var to css style

Tags: java, css, jsp, jsp-tags, include-path

Hi below is what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <c:if test="${!empty mainThemeSection}">
        <c:set var="mainTheme" value="${ mainThemeSection[0] }" />
    </c:if>
<head>
    <style>
        .text-primary {
            color: '${mainTheme.themeColour}';
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
..
</body>

</html>
```

the `${mainThemeSection.themeColour}` value is `red` or `#FFFFFF` this type of string value.
I am trying to pass a var generated in ***JSP*** to head style css so make this css bit more dynamic
But it is not working ... (***jsp and java code for themeColour definitely works***)
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare color on top of page:

```
<%String color=request.getAttribute("color");%>
```

And change

```
color: '${mainTheme.themeColour}';
```

to

```
color: '<%=color%>';
```